# JSP + JAVA + Oracle sample application

Tags: class, return, setter, getter

I am trying to create a new application in JSP, using the jsp:useBean to call the class file. I am very successful in retrieving the data from Oracle and send it to the JSP file as an arraylist. Now I am trying to send the result using a class, and with setter and getter class. I am stuck here, My JSP file is not able to understand the class file, I am not able to return  the class object from my Java file. If anyone have a sample application with setter/getter methods and pass the class object to JSP, could you please share the files with me please.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an sample application which pass the arraylist of objects to JSP. Thanks for your help everyone !